# Sequence of procedures and packages followed in a job

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, jobs

I have a scheduled job that runs every day. In that job I have called some stored procedures from various packages. I would like to know is there a sequence that is followed in Oracle i.e the sequence in which I have called them or the stored procedure are executed in any random order.

Comment: Without knowledge of exactly what you are doing this question isn't that easy to answer. If you have _one_ job then they're executed in the order you call them but it's best to see some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're saying you have a single job (vs one job for each SP) that calls packages like
begin
  pkgA.procA;
  pkgB.procB;
  pkgC.procC;
...
end;

then they are executed in the order you have them in the pl/sql anonymous block.

if you have 1 job for each API call though, then they will either execute in parallel or in any random order.